# run elasticsearch and kibanawith docker bootstrap checks failed ERROR

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

this is my first time using `elasticsearch` and I use [this link](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but when I run this command

`docker run --name es-node01 --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -t docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.1`

I got this error

`ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [1] lines before starting Elasticsearch.`

Comment: I think you need to share below logs, There are many possible bootstrap failures. I recommend to use docker-compose.yml rather docker run command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable swapping.

```
-e "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" --ulimit memlock=-1:-1
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#_disable_swapping

**EDIT:**

To use it:

```
docker run --name es-node01 --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 -t docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.1
```

Comment: how can I use that?

Comment: I updated my answer, you just need to add the above command after `docker run ...`